# JscrollBar isEnabled always return true?

Tags: junit, scrollbar

I use jfcunit and I have the following code:

```
if ((Component)event.getSource() instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    JScrollPane scrollPane= (JScrollPane) (Component)event.getSource();
                    JScrollBar scrollBar=(JScrollBar) scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                    if(!scrollBar.isVisible()||!scrollBar.isEnabled()){
                        return;
                    }
```

which runs on a mouse-wheel event and it gets it's source.
Problem is scrollBar.isVisible() works fine but scrollBar.isEnabled() always returns true even though the scrollBar is disabled and I don't seem to figure out why.

Maybe there is a property that I should check for the scroll pane or maybe I am missing something. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around it: if the visibleAmount and the maximum amount are the same it means the scrollbar is disabled:

```
   if(!scrollBar.isVisible()
||(scrollBar.getVisibleAmount()==scrollBar.getMaximum())){
                            return;
                        }
```